# Facebook Newsfeed Refresh on Android

Tags: java, android

Supposedly we're implementing a news feed with offline capability. Each time we cache the list of posts in local SQLite after calling web service to get the latest posts. What is the trigger point when we decide to call the web service? Do we base on expiration time? Or does backend notify app via FCM and app kick-starts a background service to update the local DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of an open-ended question, and the answer is: "Either, depending on the context and your team's product decisions".

Most content in social media feeds, like Facebook's, are pulled by the client. It isn't time sensitive, and the client knowns (usually) when it does and doesn't have an internet connection, so it can simply request new content when it goes online again. The exact logic of when you should pull new content is a product decision, but some common examples would be when connectivity status goes from offline to online, when the user refreshes through a button or "pull to refresh" action, and ever X minutes.

That said, there are times when a push from the server is a valid design choice. This will usually be when something is time sensitive or when new content is super infrequent. Remember, however, that a push does nothing if the client is offline, so it won't solve your issue of knowing there is new content in any better way than simply pulling new content from the server.

Beyond that, caching and expiration of caches is a complex topic that we can't really give much advice without knowing more about your app. For this, I recommend that you consider drawing a flow chart for each instance you can think of where an event should cause the app to pull new content instead of looking at the cache. There is a lot of content about how to maintain local caches of remote content, and there are a lot of solutions depending on your priorities. I recommend reading some online articles on these topics to get a better sense of the various methods and associated pitfalls of each.